# Should the volatile modifier be added to the object wake-up condition variable?

Tags: java, jvm

Please check the sample code below:

```java
private volatile int fActiveTestDeathCount;

synchronized void waitUntilFinished() {
        while (fActiveTestDeathCount < testCount()) {
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return; // ignore
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code can run normally, which is very easy to understand, but why the following code can also run normally?

```java
private int fActiveTestDeathCount;

synchronized void waitUntilFinished() {
    while (fActiveTestDeathCount < testCount()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I think that in a multi-threaded execution environment, each thread copies the fActiveTestDeathCount variable. If there is no additional volatile modifier, this variable is invisible to other threads, and the program should not work, but this is not the case.

I try to analyze whether it is that after the thread is awakened, it will automatically invalidate the variables in the thread's working memory, and then synchronize the data from the main memory? But this requires the support of memory barriers, which makes me a little confused.

Comment: 1. You definitely need `volatile`. 2.  NEVER ignore an interrupted exception.

Comment: What do you think `synchronized` does?

Comment: if you have sync, you do not need volatile. Not vice-versa though

Comment: @markspace I agree with your point of view, but in some open source projects, I found the source code without adding "volatile". I tried not to increase this modifier, which resulted in an error example, but unfortunately I did not get it.

Comment: @Khanna111  When the monitor is re-acquired after a `wait()`, does the system add a memory barrier?  I'm concerned about re-reading `fActiveTestDeathCount` after the first loop.

Comment: @David Schwartz/Khanna111  Thank you, I seem to have forgotten the fact that the code is running in a synchronized block, and any thread needs to reacquire the lock after being awakened. Because the JVM will increase the memory barrier before and after the critical section, it keeps the variables of the thread working memory updated synchronously.

Comment: @markspace Yes, re-acquisition of the lock when `wait()` returns synchronizes-with any release of the lock after a corresponding `notify()` call.

Comment: @Khanna111 When a thread is awakened, it should restart execution from the wait place, and of course it has to acquire the lock. I want to know if the thread will execute the memory barrier instruction again while holding the lock at this time?

Comment: Yes, it comes with acquiring the lock AFAIK. But you would not see stale data in any case. It would be refreshed from the main memory or pushed to the main memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `volatile` is neither required nor sufficient.

Why is it not sufficient? Because it won't stop a thread from checking `fActiveTestDeathCount` right before it is modified by another thread and then irrevocably deciding to `wait` for something that happened right after it checked.

Why is it not required? Because `synchronized` already establishes a "happens before" relationship among any two threads accessing `fActiveTestDeathCount`.

The whole point of `wait` is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation to solve precisely this race condition.

Comment: Maybe it’s worth emphasizing that it depends on what the other side is doing. If it’s writing the variable and calling `notify` within an appropriate `synchronized` block, everything works fine and `volatile` is not required. If it is not, it won’t work and `volatile` wouldn’t fix it.

Comment: @David Schwartz  After the waiting thread is awakened, it needs to acquire the lock again. At this time, the memory barrier instruction will still be executed to trigger data synchronization. Can I understand this way? Is this correct?

Comment: @Terrence Maybe, maybe not. To answer that, I'd have to understand how you are imagining the abstract Java machine works. We usually imagine it as a machine with incoherent caches, not as one that has posted writes or buffered reads. The implementation does whatever the actual, physical machine requires. Whether that's a memory barrier or something else depends on the specifics of the hardware of the physical machine.

Comment: @David Schwartz You mean it does not matter whether you add the volatile keyword or not? Do the two have no effect on the final structure? I would like to know the reasons behind them.

Comment: @Terrence In this case it doesn't matter because `synchronized` establishes a "happens before" relationship between the two threads. How the Java implementation makes that work on your hardware will vary based on the implementation and the hardware, but the Java spec says the behavior must be as if one happens before the other.